# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility, Version=15.0.0.0

Tags: c#, testing, coded-ui-tests

I'm trying to write an object framework for an application I will be testing. It's in very simple form at the moment. Written in C# on Visual Studio 2017. When I try to include references to Windows classes, e.g. 'WinWindow', I get run time errors as such:

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.dll
>
> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.WindowsStoreUtility, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have tried to find this library, but it doesn't exist on my computer and I can't find any reference on line. What do I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a license for Coded UI? CUI is not supported with all versions of Visual Studio. Make sure you have the right one.

Comment: I do have a license for Coded UI. What do you mean "make sure I have the right one"? The right license? The right version of Visual Studio? Coded UI? And how do I verify that? Answers in the form of "you can't do that" without any explanation are not helpful.

Comment: For vs2017, the assembly locates at "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies" in default. What type of project do you use? Usually, this assembly will be downloaded with Test Components when installing vs ide.

Comment: I believe Coded UI is project type and assemblies are available only when you have Visual Studio Enterprise.

Comment: I also believe we can't add Coded UI libraries to console application projects.

Comment: Agree with Naeem A Malik. Coded UI is VS Enterprise. I'm getting the same error with Windows Application Driver - Selenium. Have we referenced something from Coded UI by mistake?